# React Component Array Map - Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I'm putting together a component that will repeat list items based on an array for a set of navigation options.
I am getting the error: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';

const navOptions = [
  {name: 'Home'},
  {name: 'Me Mine and Ours'},
  {name: 'Collection'},
  {name: 'Yo!'}
];

const Nav = () => {
  navOptions.map((name, index) => {
    return (
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#" key="">j</a>
      </li>
    )
  })
};

export default Nav;
```

Comment: If you open your developer console, react now has a warning that often alerts you to these sorts of typo errors. Source: I make this mistake regularly :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `return`. You have to return the result of `navOptions.map` as well.

```
import React from 'react';

const navOptions = [
  {name: 'Home'},
  {name: 'Me Mine and Ours'},
  {name: 'Collection'},
  {name: 'Yo!'}
];

const Nav = () => {
  return navOptions.map((name, index) => {
    return (
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#" key="">j</a>
      </li>
    )
  })
};

export default Nav;
```

Comment: It also makes more sense to pass in `navOptions` as `props` to your stateless component so that `Nav` is more versatile and can be used with different options if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the main return in this part

`const Nav = () => {
  navOptions.map((name, index) => {
    return (
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#" key="">j</a>
      </li>
    )
  })
};`

Change to (I think you will need a `<div>` to wrap the `<li>`s up)

`return (<div>{navOptions.map(....`